# Ajax call not redirecting to desired page using Razor Pages

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor Pages project, and, on one of my pages, I have an AJAX call on submitting the form details. On clicking the button, I am hitting the post handler and `ModelState` is valid, but the post is not redirecting to the desired page. I have tried to debug the AJAX call using the dev tools and my success and failure functions are not being hit.

Where am I going wrong?

JavaScript

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "/Candidate/Add?handler=Candidate",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(candidate),
    success: function (data) {
        //alert('success');
        var t = data;
    },
    failure: function (data) {
        var f = data;
    }
})
```

Post handler

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostCandidateAsync([FromBody] CandidateModel candidate)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        IdTypeOptions = idTypeRepository.GetIDTypes().Result.Select(a => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = a.Id.ToString(),
            Text = a.Name
        }).ToList();

        industryOptions = industryRepository.GetIndustries().Result.Select(a => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = a.Id.ToString(),
            Text = a.Name
        }).ToList();

        GenderOptions = genderRepository.GetGender().Result.Select(g => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = g.Id.ToString(),
            Text = g.Name
        }).ToList();

        return Page();
    }


    //candidateModel.UserId = 

    var id = await candidateRepository.AddCandidate(candidate);

    //return ()
    return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
```

Comment: on ajax call your page not redirect to another page. it will give you the HTML response of that page in the success block

Comment: Sorry , I can't see how you declare candidate in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls always return some data, or a partial view, but never redirects inside of the action.

you have to fix on success of Ajax

```
.....
data: ....,
success: function (data) {
   window.location.href ...
   //or 
  window.open(....)
},
error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
  ...error code
        }
});
```

If you want to open another page use

```
window.location.href = 'http://...;' //the full url of razor page
```

If you want to open page in another window:

```
window.open('the full url of razor page');
```

Comment: the ajax call success function is not being hit in the devtools debug and neither is the failure function, so putting the window.location.href is not achieving the desired result

Comment: Debugger is never working inside of ajax. Check developer tools of the browser. YOu must be have an java error.

Comment: looking at the network section of the devtools after i exit the post handler, im getting the below values Request URL: https://localhost:44347/Candidate
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: [::1]:44347
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin , and i do not have a javascript error

Comment: @user2768586 ajax is always returning to succes or error if there is no exception,  try to change failure to error.

Answer (score -1):

I had to return JsonResult on my post handler and passed the URL I wanted to redirect to

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostCandidateAsync([FromBody] CandidateModel candidate)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        IdTypeOptions = idTypeRepository.GetIDTypes().Result.Select(a => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = a.Id.ToString(),
            Text = a.Name
        }).ToList();

        industryOptions = industryRepository.GetIndustries().Result.Select(a => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = a.Id.ToString(),
            Text = a.Name
        }).ToList();

        GenderOptions = genderRepository.GetGender().Result.Select(g => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = g.Id.ToString(),
            Text = g.Name
        }).ToList();

        return Page();
    }


    //candidateModel.UserId = 

    var id = await candidateRepository.AddCandidate(candidate);

    return new JsonResult("/Candidate/Index");
    //return ()
    //return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
```

and added the window.location.href on to the success function of the ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Candidate/Add?handler=Candidate",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(candidate),
    success: function (data) {
       
        window.location.href = data;
    },
    failure: function (data) {
        var f = data;
    }
})
```